# Azure CosmosDB: illegal characters in Document Id

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, identifier

I have the issue that the Ids that are being generated based on certain input contain the character "/". This leads to an error during the Upsert operation as "/" is not allowed in the Document id.

Which characters are not allowed beside that?
What are ways to handle such a situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The illegal characters are `/, \\, ?, #` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.resource.id?view=azure-dotnet)

Ways to deal with such a situation:

- Remove the character already in the input used for generating the id
- Replace the character in the id with another character / set of characters
- Use Hashing / Encoding (e.g. Base64)

If you know a better way please share. Thanks

Comment: Base64 encoding can return / in the result, so illegal characters are possible still, right?

Comment: `System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode` will encode all of those characters using % escape sequences.

Answer (score 0):

I'm base64 encoding the plaintext. Then replacing the '/' and '=' that can still be there from base64 with '-' and '_' respectively. This seems to be working well. I ran into other issues when I just tried UrlEncode the value.

Psuedo:

## ```js
var encoded = String.ConvertToBase64(plainTextId);
var preppedId = encoded.Replace('/','-').Replace('=','_');
```